# "Infinity% unanswered" showing up on tag "top users" page

Tags: bug

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-vnext/topusers (though it doesn't always happen)

I've recently been retagging some questions and thus removing questions from a given tag. As such, quite often there end up being no questions within the last 7 or last 30 days. It *sometimes* shows this erroneous result:

```
0      Last 7 Days     Infinity% unanswered
0      Last 30 Days    Infinity% unanswered  
142    All Time        19.7% unanswered
```

[image: Screenshot of Inifinity%]

But if I wait a while (presumably due to some caching), it gets fixed to correctly say:

```
0      Last 7 Days     0% unanswered
0      Last 30 Days    0% unanswered  
142    All Time        19.7% unanswered
```

Comment: If 0 questions are there, *any* percentage is technically correct. That said, its a pretty funny bug.

Comment: They recently hired Buzz Lightyear at the office...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET actually, only 0% would be correct. If there are no questions, then there can be no unanswered questions <_<

Comment: @Compass Sure, but 100% of 0 is still 0, so is 3% and Infinity percent. Granted Infinity * 0 is undefined, but this isn't Math.SE :)

Comment: I get 0% unanswered

Comment: @DavidGrinberg "if I wait a while (presumably due to some caching), it gets fixed"

Comment: I would have expected NaN%, it's 0/0 after all

Comment: In JavaScript, dividing by 0 gives "Infinity" as the result.

Comment: @TravisJ Not if you divide 0 by 0.

Comment: @harold Javascript, you get `Infinity`, mathmatically, you get `undefined`, `NaN`, or `NEI`.

Comment: @Ajedi32 - # questions / # unanswered would presumably be the set we are looking at. So if there were 0 asked, you are right it would be NaN. If there were any number asked and none answered, we are back to Infinity :)

Comment: @TravisJ yes, but nything `/ 0` = `NaN`, this is just a JavaScript bug.

Comment: @Wyatt there's no such "bug", it is perfectly spec'ed behavior.

Comment: @TravisJ Not quite. If there were any number (n) asked and none answered, then it would be `0/n`, not `n/0`.

Comment: It's a back-end code bug. Not JavaScript. In C#, 1.0 / 0.0 == Infinity

Comment: @Ajedi32 in that case, `n/0` is the same thing, and still `=== NaN`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I understand that, but it's a *bug* because it's mathematically incorrect.

Comment: @Wyatt No, *nothing* in JavaScript `=== NaN`, not even `NaN` itself. Aside from that though, I said it *wouldn't* be `n/0`. It's `<number of questions answered>` / `<number of questions>`, not the other way around.

Comment: @JamesLawruk - Good point, it could also be in c#. Though I don't think it is a bug. In c# 1.0/0.0 is Infinity, while 0.0/0.0 is NaN.

Comment: @Ajedi32 - It is clearly n/0 because that is the only way that Infinity would be shown.

Comment: I never directly said that `x === NaN` in JavaScript, but in the real world, `n/0` = NaN.

Comment: @TravisJ Well it could be, but if so that's probably the cause of the bug. There are 0 questions total, and 0 questions answered. Therefore, the percentage of questions answered should be `0/0`, not `1/0`.

Comment: @Ajedi32 either way, it's `0/0`, so it's not JS anyway, because JS evaulates that as `NaN`.

Comment: And in this case, 0 zeroiths cam equal any percentage, so it's correct anyway.

Comment: @Wyatt It is correct. 0 in javascript is infinitesimal (there's a +0 and -0), there is no true zero representation. The reciprocal of an infinitesimal is infinite.

Comment: ***Yay!***: http://puu.sh/fC4sl/5db3d26f2e.png

Comment: @bjb568 infinitesimal isn't a number, and therefor has no reciprocal.

Comment: @Wyatt It's a set of pseudo-numbers which all have infinite reciprocals. 0 in javascript is *an* infinitesimal.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a possible explanation, which may be obvious to many of you. One question tagged `asp.net-vnext` was asked and answered seven days ago. So the code to calculate answered questions returns 1. Perhaps the value 1 is stored in cache. Now the code which calculates total tagged questions executes sometime later. By this time, it is passed seven days, so it returns 0 total questions. When the percentage calculation is done, 1.0 / 0.0 evaluates to Infinity.

```
double answered = 1;
double total = 0;
double percentage = answered / total * 100;
Console.WriteLine(percentage);//Infinity
```

Comment: You might link to [a post that explains that `.net` products actually return that value (instead of an error) in some cases of divide-by-zero](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4609698/).  This behavior is not obvious to those who avoid Micros**t products AMAP.

Comment: @Brock Yeah following the IEEE 754 spec is *incredibly* surprising indeed. Compared to Java which.. oh well.

Comment: @Voo, Too bad the IEEE 754 spec doesn't follow the rules of fundamental math, wherein [division by zero is undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero).  That spec even has signed zeroes! You can hardly blame an engineer for not taking it seriously -- even if it does have its practical uses.