# Posts % listed as Infinity in user profile "top tags" section

Tags: bug, profile-page

If a new user has their first answer deleted, then the relevant tag will show up in the "Top Tags" section of their profile, with Posts % equal to infinity. Here's an example:

[image]

Basically, the post is being counted in the numerator of the calculation but not the denominator. I could see two alternatives, both of which seem more consistent to me:

1. Don't list information for deleted posts in the Top Tags section
2. Use deleted posts in the denominator when computing the "Posts %" part of the Top Tags section.

This seems similar in nature to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285446/infinity-unanswered-showing-up-on-tag-top-users-page), which dealt with "Infinity percent" issues for tag top users pages.

Comment: *To Infinity and Beyond!*

Comment: @MartijnPieters it was begging to be said!

Comment: Weird... it isn't another Jon Skeet awesome bug

Comment: I couldn't find any official source to whether such mutations of bugs should be addressed in answers to the original bug post, but it seemed logical to me. Let me know if this is frowned upon.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to post a new bug report, then bumped into this one. I've probably encountered a milder case of the same issue: one of 2 questions of a new user got deleted.

Result:

[image: it's over 9000! (no, it's not)]

Initially I thought that [caching was to blame](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/), but this thread tells me that it might be a permanent problem of partially including deleted posts in the tag percentage calculation.

Suggestion: always include deleted posts in the denominator of the percentage calculation as well, and not just in the numerator.

### Update:

A few days later I checked in again with said user. They've asked a new question, still in the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag. Their top tag info now:

[image: updated version: back to 100%]

This means that only the 2 undeleted questions count in their tag score, and correspondingly the maximum is back to 100%. This would suggest that (at least my version of the issue) is indeed due to caching. It would be nice to know if this meta question's original infinity-scored case would persist for days.